# running python on VSC failed

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I've tried to run different python and ipy code on Visual Studio Code (v=1.61.2) but every time I got the error:
`Extension activation failed, run the 'Developer: Toggle Developer Tools' command for more information.` I installed some relevant Extensions already but none of them doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: How do you run your code?

Comment: Run and Debug or F5

Comment: it lacks information to judge, could you have a look at this [link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/6863)? Then you can know how to get the error message. And could you try to reinstall the python extension or downgrade it?

Comment: I checked the link out as well as reinstalled the python extension but none of them  worked. The error that I got is the same: `Extension activation failed, run the 'Developer: Toggle Developer Tools' command for more information.
Python extension loading...`